# How to show $\phi$ is a bijection between two set of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I am reading the proof for the correspondence theorem in group theory:

> $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism $G_1 \longrightarrow G_2$, then $\phi$ is a bijection between A={subgroups of $G_1$ contains the kernal($\phi$)} and B={subgroups of $G_2$}

I know there are couple ways to state this theorem (subgroups of the $G/S$ correspond to the subgroups of $G$ containing $S$), but this is the version I am working on

(I already proved that $\phi(A) \in B$ **domain A codomain B** and $\phi^{-1}(B) \in A$)

Question:
Generally when I want to prove something is a bijection, I show that its **one to one** and **onto**: $$f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$$ $$ \forall x \in B \implies f(y) = x, y\in A$$
Here I can show $\phi$ is **one to one** by proving that preimage is unique: $$\phi^{-1}(\phi(x)) = x, x \in A$$
Do I need to worry about **onto**? my notes suggest that I prove: $$\phi(\phi^{-1}(y)) = y, y \in B$$
But I already showed that $\phi^{-1}(y) \in A$ is that not enough? am I missing something in my proof?

Comment: I don't think $\phi^{-1}(y) \in A$ proves the onto part.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/955413/589.

Answer (score 1):

You may know $\phi^{-1}(y)\in A$, but does that imply $\phi(\phi^{-1}(y))=y?$

In general, suppose you have a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ between some sets $A$ and $B$. Another way to say $f$ is bijective, is to say there is a function $g: B \rightarrow A$ such that $g\circ f (a) = a$ for all $a\in A$, and $f\circ g (b)=b$ for all $b\in B$. The condition $g\circ f(a)=a$ is equivalent to $f$ being one-to-one, and $f\circ g(b)=b$ is equivalent to $f$ being onto.

Here you have $f=\phi$, $g=\phi^{-1}$. You have shown $g\circ f(a)=a$, but not $f\circ g(b)=b$. Showing $\phi^{-1}(b)\in A$ just says $\phi^{-1}$ is a function from $B$ to $A$.

Comment: I can show that $\phi^{-1}(b) \in A, \forall b \in B$ does that prove onto?

Comment: That does not prove it's onto. You need to show that every element of $b$ can be obtained by applying $\phi$. The problem is that you're calling the map $\phi^{-1}$ before you've proved that it has all the necessary properties. Forget that it's called $\phi^{-1}$ for a moment, and call it $\psi$. How does knowing that $\psi(b)\in A$ show that $b = \phi(a)$ for some $a\in A$?